# Received a failure event for test with unknown id '5.14'. Registered test ids: '[:my.project:test, 5.1]'

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

It seems that I've stumbled over an issue that is a bit hard to dissect.
We've added a new JUnit test run listener to allow an extra test reporting service to be implemented. This was working fine in Oracle JDK 8 + Gradle 5.1 + JUnit-foundation 9.4.2.

However since updating to Java OpenJDK 11.0.3 + Gradle 5.1 or 5.4.1 + JUnit-foundation 9.4.2 or 9.4.3 our tests fail to report correctly. The tests still succeed, but Gradle reports errors (see below) and therefore fails the build.

I'm looking for hints to pinpoint what is going wrong.

When disabling the extra plugin my tests and reporting works fine using Java 11. However, the extra JUnit test run listener is still needed.

I've tried updating to newer versions of Gradle (5.4.1) and JUnit-foundation (9.4.3). But alas, no changes.

Adding JUnit-foundation using

```
ext {
        junitFoundation = configurations.testRuntime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.find {
            it.name == 'junit-foundation'
        }
    }
    test.doFirst {
        jvmArgs "-javaagent:${junitFoundation.file}"
        testClassesDirs.forEach { dir ->
            println "Test classes dir: ${dir}"
        }
    }
```

Expected successful gradle build, received the following (anonymized) output:

```
> Configure project :
.... removed my project output ....

Received a failure event for test with unknown id '5.14'. Registered test ids: '[:my.project:test, 5.1]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a failure event for test with unknown id '5.14'. Registered test ids: '[:my.project:test, 5.1]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.failure(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.failure(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '5.14'. Registered test ids: '[:my.project:test, 5.1]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '5.14'. Registered test ids: '[:my.project:test, 5.1]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor257.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Gradle Test Executor 5 STANDARD_ERROR
    Jun 14, 2019 11:34:21 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
    WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to execute tests
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.TestOutputRedirector.setOutputOwner(TestOutputRedirector.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.CaptureTestOutputTestResultProcessor.completed(CaptureTestOutputTestResultProcessor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.actor.internal.DefaultActorFactory$BlockingActor.dispatch(DefaultActorFactory.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.actor.internal.DefaultActorFactory$BlockingActor.dispatch(DefaultActorFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.completed(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestExecutionListener.executionFinished(JUnitPlatformTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$executionFinished$5(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.notifyTestExecutionListeners(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:59)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.access$100(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:28)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.executionFinished(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:92)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ExecutionListenerAdapter.executionFinished(ExecutionListenerAdapter.java:56)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.reportUnexpectedFailure(RunnerExecutor.java:51)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.stop(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


> Task :my.project:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my.project:test'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':my.project:test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.started(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.started(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:38)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    ... 3 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 9s
12 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 11 up-to-date
```

Comment: The gradle issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6453 seems related to the issue I'm experiencing. However, the provided workaround does not work. So I think it might still be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit foundation is a workaround for the Gradle design decision (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330#issuecomment-303123535)  to provide an alternative method for the JUnit specific RunListener. The alternative provided by Gradle is the org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener interface (and AbstractTestTask that implements it). This will require some work to convert to. They designed it this way to allow test listeners to work for JUnit 4, and 5 and TestNG, etc.

So my answer to my own question is: You shouldn't do things this way when you're using Gradle.